# Guessing patterns of symbolic series

Tags: string-manipulation, polynomials

I have a system of `2s+1` equations, where `s` can take integer values of `{1,2,3,....,n}`. Here are the list of equations and variables and the solution command.

```
equations[s_] := Join[
  {(1 + d) v - price[0] + b (a surplus[1] + (1 - a) surplus[0]) == 
    0 + b ( surplus[0])},
  Table[(1 + d) v - price[x] + 
     b (a surplus[x + 1] + (1 - a) surplus[x]) == 
    v + b (a surplus[x] + (1 - a) surplus[x - 1]), {x, 1, s - 1}], 
  Table[surplus[x] == 
    x /n ( (1 + d) v + 
        b (a surplus[x] + (1 - a) surplus[x - 1])) + (1 - x /
        n) ((1 + d) v - price[x] + 
        b (a surplus[x + 1] + (1 - a) surplus[x])), {x, 0, 
    s - 1}], {surplus[s] == 
    s /n ((1 + d) v + 
        b (a surplus[s] + (1 - a) surplus[s - 1])) + (1 - s /n) (v + 
        b (a surplus[s] + (1 - a) surplus[s - 1]))}
  ]
variables[s_] := 
 Join[Table[price[x], {x, 0, s - 1}], Table[surplus[x], {x, 0, s}]]

solLs[s_] := Solve[equations[s], variables[s]] /. surplus[-1] -> 0;
```

When solving this system for specific values of `s` e.g., `s=1`, we can see `solLs[1]` to be resulted

```
{{price[0] -> ((n + d (n + a (b - b n))) v)/(n - a b n), 
  surplus[0] -> 0, surplus[1] -> ((d + n) v)/(n - a b n)}}
```

getPrice[i_] := price[i] /. solLs[i + 2][[1, i + 1]]

now I was able to find the pattern using

```
FindSequenceFunction[{getPrice[0], getPrice[1], getPrice[2], 
  getPrice[3], getPrice[4], getPrice[5]}]
```

We have

```
price(i) = v ( ((((1 - a) b)/(1 - a b))^i)   /((1 - a)  b ) + 
   d  (( b +  n  (1 - b) - ((((1 - a) b)/(1 - a b))^
      i) )/( (1 - b)  n)))
```

Comment: Difficult with only four terms. [`FindSequenceFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindSequenceFunction.html) seems to work with six (?) or more terms. There seem to be terms `(1 - b^(i - 1))/(1 - b)` and `(-1)^i a^i b^(i - 1)` but the rest is hard to guess.

Comment: It might help if you explain a bit the background of your problem: Where does this series come from? How did you generate the first four terms? ...

Comment: Thank you for your interest in helping me. I did provide the background of the problem. The main missing part is guessing the polynomial form of X. There might be easier ways to approach this problem. So if you have any other way, I would love to learn it.

Comment: It might be helpful to give a function that generates the desired `price` values such as `getPrice[i_] := price[i] /. solLs[i + 2][[1, i + 1]]`.

Comment: You can transform your system of linear equations by writing equations in the form `lhs ==0` and then using for instance `CoefficientArrays[equations[7], variables[7]]`. Quite an interesting block matrix arises. You can use this insight to guess a general solution.

Comment: Thank you all. I was able to use comments Roman and JimB made to solve my problem.